# Automake configure wrong target type aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu

Tags: docker, gcc, apple-m1, arm64, automake

I'm trying to (cross)compile my automake project, which is originally developed for linux/x86_64, within a docker container running on an Apple Macbook with M1 chip.

The docker host (mac) is `version 20.10.14, build a224086`

The base image is `debian:stable`, here's the very basic Dockerfile:

```
FROM debian:stable
USER root

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y upgrade

RUN apt-get -y install build-essential libtool git gperf gengetopt python3-dev \
    libsm-dev libjpeg-dev libtiff-dev libxerces-c-dev \
     libre2-dev libpcap-dev libsqlite3-dev libsysfs-dev vim

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash"]
```

`gcc -v` inside the container gives me:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/10/lto-wrapper
Target: aarch64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Debian 10.2.1-6' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-10/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++,m2 --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-10 --program-prefix=aarch64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-bootstrap --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-libquadmath --disable-libquadmath-support --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --enable-libphobos-checking=release --with-target-system-zlib=auto --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --enable-fix-cortex-a53-843419 --disable-werror --enable-checking=release --build=aarch64-linux-gnu --host=aarch64-linux-gnu --target=aarch64-linux-gnu --with-build-config=bootstrap-lto-lean --enable-link-mutex
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd
gcc version 10.2.1 20210110 (Debian 10.2.1-6)
```

All the binaries of the compiler toolchain are a symlink to the actual `aarch64-xxx` variant, such as:

```
/usr/bin/gcc-10 -> /usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc-10
/usr/bin/g++-10 -> /usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-g++-10
/usr/bin/ld -> /usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-ld
```

If I configure my project, it fails with an unknown target:

```
$ export TARGET=aarch64-linux-gnu
$ export BUILD=aarch64-linux-gnu
$ export HOST=aarch64-linux-gnu

$ ../../src/configure --build=aarch64-linux-gnu --host=aarch64-linux-gnu --target=aarch64-linux-gnu

<SNIP>

checking build system type... aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c

<SNIP>

unknown target aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu
```

Where on earth is the `unknown` in `aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu` coming from, when everything in my toolchain says `aarch64-linux-gnu`?

Is it possible that this is a result of the output generated by one of `libtoolize`, `aclocal`, `autoconf`, `autoheader` or `automake`?

Comment: `unknown` is fine, it's the vendor part, like `pc` or `ubuntu`, you can ignore it. But here, it's hard to tell you the problem, can you share all the ouput before the error?
Else, for now, if you want to build for intel and not arm, you can build and start your container with `--platform linux/amd64`

Comment: @jmaitrehenry I'm sorry, the problem was home-grown. We had a falsy check in configure.ac that exits whenever the cpu type doesn't match a certain pattern. Nobody came across aarch64 before, so there's that. However, thank you very much for the `--platform` docker arg. It's veeery slow, but it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well that's embarrassing. We have a check for the cpu type in our `configure.ac` and nobody came across `aarch64` before, so that check entered the default case every time, which was to exit.

Comment: Would you mind accepting this answer so this question shows up as answered?